iOS: Force clock to be displayed at all times
Is there a way to make the iPhone always display the current time, even in full-screen apps?
(Or maybe a way to at least force it to while in specified apps?)
I understand why some people would want to forget what time it is and allow themselves to become absorbed in their game or video or whatever. I also understand why some developers might want people to forget about everything else and just continue using their app. "Engagement metrics are up! Hooray!"
But there are times when I still need to keep an eye on the time, and... oops!
And exiting to the home screen to check the time, only to find that you didn't need stop what you were doing because you've still got a few minutes - that's annoying too. That then leads to a reluctance to leave the app, and imprecisely guessing what time it is instead.
Yes, the alarm feature is helpful for some cases, but not all. I'm not always trying to alert everybody.
Sucks to be late a few minutes despite carrying a "clock" at all times, because sometimes it won't show the time.

People managed to be on time BEFORE smartphones... The aphorism that this generation is only smart when they have their phone with them...

Being a Father of children who have been diagnosed with ADHD, I can understand the need to know the time and ways to manage it.
If you swipe down from the top center of your screen, in any app, you will view the Notification Center. From there, you will see the time.

While not as ideal as an always-visible clock, this workaround is definitely better than exiting the app. Thank you for this tip. I hadn't thought of using Notification Center in this way.
